# Is Tailwind CSS change its sizing rules recently?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, spacing

I'm using Tailwind CSS last couple of months. I can notice there are some issues with the sizing parameters i.e., font size, padding, margin, etc. Is there any issue with this?
Or I can assume, this is a problem with my local files?

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem (and self-answer) are not helpful. The cause was just that the poster was zoomed in on his/her browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon me, this was a very silly problem. I was trying with a 200% zoom screen. Very funny!